# Android Studio/emulator extremely slow

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android development, and I am having problems with Android Studio and the emulator. Both running together slow both systems to a crawl. My machine has Windows 10 Home and Linux Mint KDE 18.2 on it.

I have been trying to get it to work on both OSes. On Windows 10, I have 4gb of RAM, HAXM installed, and everything closed, it is somewhat usable (not much).

On Linux, I have 10gb of RAM (because of swap space). On KDE, it does not work at all. On fluxbox (with everything else closed), it is doable, but still slow.

In Android Studio (on Linux), I have increased the VM heap to 2gb, and enabled offline gradle work. With the emulator, I am using the Nexus 5x emulator (api v. 7.1.1, x86_64) with the device frame turned off, the RAM at 1024, and the heap at 256.

On Linux, memory does not seem to be the issue; when I open a system monitor, it shows both processors running at 100%. Basically, what can I can I do now?

If anyone needs any more info, just ask. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I did see this question: [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)
This question is about the android emulator w/ eclipse. Also, I have tried  the suggestions in that post. The suggestion I would like to do (use a snapshot) does not seem to be present in Android Studio (v 2.3.3).

Comment: what's your disk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Comment: Try to use Genymotion

Comment: which SDK are you using?

Comment: @TimCastelijns See my edit

Comment: @jigarsavaliya SDK version 7.1.1 (Nougat)

Comment: try to change SDK on running emulator. you have to change to some lower level api and than again change to 25,this is work for me ,hope for you.